# WP7 - Bing Maps - How do I handle multiple pushpins on a MapItemsControl? - currently crashing application

Tags: windows-phone-7, bing-maps

My bing map application eventually crashes when I drag or zoom. Tested on emulator and device.

I have installed the October update.

MapItemsControl binding to ObservableCollection.
When application starts, pins have been loaded and are visible.

While troubleshooting, I determine the app will not crash if the pushpins on the map are in the same general area. Example,

```
addPin("40.78184126814031", "-73.97712707519532");    
addPin("40.74569634433956", "-73.96717071533204");    
addPin("40.7117682299881", "-74.0125322341919");    
addPin("40.75777392583087", "-73.96950960159302");
```

But if the pins are spread out - the application crashes when the user zooms into one specific pin and/or dragging the map. Example,

```
addPin("42.35960626034072", "-71.09212160110473");    
addPin("51.388066116760086", "30.098590850830067");    
addPin("48.17972265679143", "11.54910385608672");    
addPin("40.28802528051879", "-76.65668606758117");
```

Not sure if the project code is necessary - I am assuming there is some concept that I just do not know about.

Any suggestions - I am all ears.
Stack trace below.

Thanks

```
Unspecified error
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)    
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.UIElement_HitTestPoint(UIElement element, Point ptHit)    
   at System.Windows.UIElement.HitTest(Point point)    
   at System.Windows.Media.VisualTreeHelper.FindElementsInHostCoordinates(Point intersectingPoint, UIElement subtree)    
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps.Core.TouchHelper.<InputHitTest>d__0.MoveNext()    
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps.Core.TouchHelper.HitTestAndRaiseDownEvent(UIElement root, TouchPoint touchPoint)    
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps.Core.TouchHelper.TouchFrameReported(Object sender, TouchFrameEventArgs e)    
   at System.Windows.Input.Touch.OnTouch(Object sender, TouchFrameEventArgs e)    
   at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.RaiseEvent(IntPtr target, UInt32 eventId, IntPtr coreEventArgs, UInt32 eventArgsTypeIndex)
```

Thought it best to include the code - running this and zooming in crashes app - thanks

PINDATA class

```
namespace BugCrash.models
{public class PinData{public GeoCoordinate PinLocation { get;set; }}}
```

MAINPAGE.xaml.cs

```
namespace BugCrash
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        private ObservableCollection<PinData> _pinsA = new ObservableCollection<PinData>();
        public ObservableCollection<PinData> PinsA { get { return this._pinsA; } }

        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
            myMap.Center = new GeoCoordinate(40.74569634433956, -73.96717071533204);
            myMap.ZoomLevel = 4;
            MessageBox.Show(loadAPins_fromString());
        }

        //ADD PIN TO COLLECTION
    private void addPin(String lat, String lon)
    {
        PinData tmpPin;
        tmpPin = new PinData() { PinLocation = new GeoCoordinate(System.Convert.ToDouble(lat), System.Convert.ToDouble(lon)) };
        _pinsA.Add(tmpPin);
    }    
        //LOAD PINS ONE BY ONE
       private string loadAPins_fromString()
        {
            //BAD
            addPin("42.35960626034072", "-71.09212160110473");
            addPin("51.388066116760086", "30.098590850830067");
            addPin("48.17972265679143", "11.54910385608672");
            addPin("40.28802528051879", "-76.65668606758117");
            return "A PINS LOADED - STRING";
        }
    }
}
```

MAINPAGE.xaml

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
    x:Class="BugCrash.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"   
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="768"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="False" 
    xmlns:my="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <!--RESOURCES-->
        <Grid.Resources>
            <my:ApplicationIdCredentialsProvider ApplicationId="XX" x:Key="MyCredentials"/>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <my:Map Height="768"              
                 Name="myMap" 
                 VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="480"
                CredentialsProvider="{StaticResource MyCredentials}">
            <my:Map.Mode>
                <my:AerialMode ShouldDisplayLabels="True" />
            </my:Map.Mode>

            <my:MapItemsControl
                    x:Name="GroupAPins" 
                    ItemsSource="{Binding PinsA}"                   
                    >
                <my:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <my:Pushpin Location="{Binding PinLocation}" Width="60"  Height="55" Content="PIN">
                        </my:Pushpin>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </my:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </my:MapItemsControl>
        </my:Map>
    </Grid>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Answer (score 5):

I had to go to microsoft to get an answer for this.
Turns out there is bug in the map control.
To get around this bug - load the bing map control dynamically.

Changes are as follows,

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
        //Create a map.
        Map MyMap = new Map();
        MyMap.CredentialsProvider = new ApplicationIdCredentialsProvider("XX");

        //Remove the List of items from the resource and add it to the map
        this.LayoutRoot.Resources.Remove("GroupAPins");
        MyMap.Children.Add(GroupAPins);

        MyMap.Center = new GeoCoordinate(40.74569634433956, -73.96717071533204);
        MyMap.ZoomLevel = 5;

        //Add the map to the content panel.
        ContentPanel.Children.Add(MyMap);
        loadAPins_fromString();
    }
```

and the XAML,

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <!--RESOURCES-->
    <Grid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="LogoTemplate">
            <my:Pushpin Location="{Binding PinLocation}" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <my:MapItemsControl x:Name="GroupAPins"
                    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource LogoTemplate}"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding PinsA}">
        </my:MapItemsControl>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,0,12,0"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Did not help me... still my application crashes.

Answer (score 4):

Ahhh code writing.
Turns out I can prevent the app from crashing by removing the width and height from the pushpin.

The Microsoft solution didn't include pushpin width and height - so I assumed creating the map control dynamically was the answer - but adding the width and height - same crash as my original app.

I need to change my code back to the original version with the map control in the XAML - and remove the pushpin width and height to see if it solves both versions -  but this seems to be the problem - my app is now running fine - dynamically created map control - pushpin with no width or height.

Anyway - hope this helps someone.

-D

Comment: I've just had my app throw this exception. I'm not setting pushpin width or height, though the pushpins do have buttons as child controls with BorderThickness="0" Padding="0" set.